# Eclipse RCP 3.x plugin doesn't work correct with Eclipse 4.x

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have Eclipse plugin that has been written under Eclisep 3.7 RCP. With Eclipse 3.x it works fine, but when I tried to use my Plugin in Eclipse 4.x (Juno or Kepler), I noticed 
that my custom view that extends org.eclipse.ui.part.ViewPart is beeing duplicated by every switch of perspective 
(Clarification: by evry switch to perspective that wasn't opened yet)

Consider if current perspective is 'Java', then my view is opened once (what is desired), now I switch workspace
to 'Debug' - my view is beeing duplicated, now to annother perspective - view is opened three times, etc...

Eclipse console shows no errors or anything else. I tried to migrate my plugin by adding of extra plugins
according to http://www.vogella.com/articles/Eclipse4MigrationGuide/article.html (chapter 1.3) but it seems that still doesn't work correct.

Could someone give me a tip what could went wrong or where is a problem in my case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you migrate to Kepler you will have to add org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.workbench to dependecies
and also add an addon in the application model [(see table)](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseRCP/article.html#runconfiguration_problems2).

In eclipse e4, you don't need to extend to viewpart anymore because of the dependency injection. I my self tryed migration but soon I realised that adaption is better, most importantly to understand the differences between e3 and e4. If you do the [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseRCP/article.html) you will understand and be able to change your code so that it will work.